# Why do some functions recognize this global variable but others don't?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, global-variables, global

So I have the following JS function that adds rows to a table based on a global list, `events`. Events starts out empty and I have another function pushing dict object into it. Items are pushed to the list successfully, however, when `events` reaches `fillTable()`, it's empty. In the code below, the first `console.log(events)` (inside `fillTable()`), prints an empty list but the second `console.log(events)` prints the data as expected. `events` isn't being defined anywhere else so I am lost.

```
events = []

function otherFunction(repo, type, url) {
    events.push({'repo': repo, 'type': type, 'url': url})
}

function fillTable() {

    console.log(events);         // {}
    console.log(events.length);  // 0

    var table = document.getElementById("table")
    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        let event = events[i];

        const repo = document.createElement('td')
        repo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(event['repo']));

        const type = document.createElement('td')
        type.appendChild(document.createTextNode(event['type']));
        
        const url = document.createElement('td')
        url.appendChild(document.createTextNode(event['url']));

        const row = document.createElement('tr')
        row.appendChild(repo);
        row.appendChild(type);
        row.appendChild(url);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}

otherFunction('a', 'b', 'c');
console.log(events);         // {'repo': 'a', 'type': 'b', 'url': 'c'}
console.log(events.length);  // 1

fillTable();
```

Comment: I tested it and am getting the events logged when calling the filltable function. You should give more of your code, specifically showing where and how you call filltable

Comment: @Santaclaus This code is embedded in an HTML file so I call it just like how it's shown there when the page loads. I also tried just returning `events` at the end of `otherFunction()` but that didn't change anything. I also added another `console.log(events)` after calling `fillTable()` and that returns the events so it seems like `events` is only empty inside `fillTable()`?

Comment: From what I can see, there is no reason why that should be happening. I've tried it out and have gotten the events logged in both instances, is there anymore to your code?

Comment: @Santaclaus Events is printing all the items in all cases but inside `fillTable()`, `events.length = 0` and I can't iterate over it so it prints but doesn't actually exist within the function? I posted the full script here https://gist.github.com/ttamre/2cf02f7cd0b226f0c01f97fbc0b23a07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with your usage of async functions.

```
events = []
getGithubActivity();//this function makes an xmlHttp request
fillTable();//this function is called straight after. There has been no chance for a return of the xmlHttp request.
```

i suggest placing fillTable like this

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            try {
                //add events
               fillTable();
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log('getGithubActivity() - Error: ' + e);
            }
        }
    };
```

When you log an object in console. It will update upon being opened, this is why it appears filled to you even though at the time of logging the length was 0. By the time you open it in console, the request has returned.

Also I noticed that eventList isn't defined anywhere, could this possibly be a typo?

Comment: Actually just moving fillTable won't be enough. Inside your getGithubActivity() you also start another request for each event. So you will have to consider that. Anyways, the idea is the same, you can't call fillTable until all the events have been added. I'll be happy to help with this if required.

Comment: 1. Yea thats a typo, `eventList` should be `events`

2. That makes sense. Is there a way to have `fillTable()` wait until the requests are complete?

Comment: I changed `fillTable()` so it's now a callback function to add a single row to the table, and I call it in `getUrl()`. Everything works now, thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. You should make an edit to your question that explains the problem so that perhaps this post can useful to other veiwiers.